# vagrant slow page load after 60 seconds from last request

Tags: php, performance, laravel, vagrant

My Vagrant box running a classic LAMP stack (ubuntu 14, php 5.5.9) serves pages slowly (~ 5.3/5.5 secs) if more than 60 seconds passed since last page load. The "normal" page load (before passing the 60 secs limit) is ~0.2 sec. The application files are shared from the host system via NFS.

What I've debugged so far:

- it only happens to requests hitting the application (which is a
  laravel 5 application)
- happens even if no queries are made to the db
- if I die() at the very top of the application it is fast
- static files are always served fast
- serving the files from the native filesystem is fast
- this sort of 60 seconds timer is reset even if requests are made to a different application (on the same server)

Any hints on what could be causing this ? I think it is clearly related to the large number of files that need to be accessed on NFS, but the 60 seconds thing seems weird to me...

Comment: maybe this is related ? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-7009/chapter3-53/index.html

Comment: How long does it take you to access a single one of those files shared via NFS?

Comment: reading a single file is fast, but loading the whole application is not

Comment: If you're using virtualbox for the virtualization, you should instead be using the Shared Folders feature. Its much much faster.

Comment: I moved to NFS from shared folders because of the slowness...

Answer (score 4):

The problem was related to NFS attribute caching (that lasts 60 seconds by default) and solved it by setting the following mount options:

```
'nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime,actimeo=1'
```

See: [Speed up sync latency between host and guest on Vagrant (NFS sync folders)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818907/speed-up-sync-latency-between-host-and-guest-on-vagrant)